# How to push mean of numbers twards largest one?

Tags: means

I have some numbers mostly less than 1, and a few of them are negative. How can I calculate mean of them so it will skew towards the largest number? for example my numbers are:   $1.2, 0.01, 0.1, -0.2 $. so the mean of them is:
$$ (1.2+0.01+0.1-0.2)/4=0.227 $$
but if I calculates the mean like this:
$$ \left(\sqrt1.2 + \sqrt0.01 + \sqrt1.01 - \sqrt(|-0.2|)\right)^2/4 = 0.283 $$
my question is does calculating mean of numbers in this way pushes the mean of numbers towards the largest number in all cases? If yes, how can I prov that? If no, how should I calculate the mean?

Comment: This is simply not the mean anymore

Comment: I know, as I don't know the name of this calculation, I said kind of mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called a [smooth maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_maximum) function. Wikipedia gives the example of a weighted average function, where the weight of each $x_i$ is set to $e^{\alpha x_i}$. If $\alpha=0$ then we recover the unweighted average, also known as the arithmetic mean of the data. As $\alpha\to\infty$, the weighted average approaches the maximum of the data. So you can decide how large you want $\alpha$ to be, depending on how far you want to push away from the mean and towards the largest number.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re proposing is a sort of reversal of a common type of average called [root mean square](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square), so you could call it a “square mean root”.  It has two obvious drawbacks:

1. It completely ignores the sign of the negative values;
2. It is only weakly effective at highlighting the largest value.

In fact it is **worse** than the regular mean. The only reason it “won” in your example was because you effectively replaced the -0.2 with 0.2: had you done so for the usual mean it would have been 0.327 which is higher than the square-mean-root.

The RMS is definitely better than your proposal for accentuating large values, but it still shares the drawback of erasing negative signs.  Since you call them out specifically I am going to assume that you care about this, otherwise you should just simplify your original question to consider positive values.

One approach is to generalize further to [generalized means](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#) which admit a parameter $p$ (in your example $p=\frac12$ and in the case of RMS $p=2$).  These are in generally only defined for sets of nonnegative reals.  But by restricting $p$ to be an odd positive integer, the same definition works for a mixture of positive and negative values, but it has the following modified convergence property:

> Let $X$ be a nonempty finite sequence of real numbers and let $m := \max \{|x| : x \in X \}$, the largest absolute value in $X$.  Suppose $m$ occurs exactly $a$ times in $X$ and $-m$ occurs exactly $b$ times in $X$.  If $a\ne b$ then $$\lim_{p\to \infty \\ p\text{ odd}} M_p(S) = \begin{cases}+x & \text{if }a>b,\\ -x & \text{if }a< b.\end{cases}$$ If $a=b$, this limit reduces to the same limiting mean as $X$ with all copies of $\pm m$ removed (if this results in an empty set, the limit is 0).

So this picks out the largest value in $X$ except when there are ties between the most negative and most positive values, in which case it becomes a popularity contest.  If you are looking for the largest *absolute* value only, then you could just take absolute values first and there will be no tiebreaker needed.  If you are looking for the largest *positive* value only (i.e. if the set is $\{1,-100\}$ you want to pick out the $1$), then you should follow Chris Culter’s answer.